# Am I thinking in correct way when I need to SelectMany observables?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

So it's possible I will end up with several questions about the following code, maybe because I am using a `Subject` and I am not sure if its OK to use or not.

This is difficult for me to explain, I don't know why, maybe I am lacking the terminology.

What I am trying to do is have 1 type that can register several observables with it, so I can pass this type around and group up all the observables and expose a a single observable from it.

So my **first question** I get a feeling I am not thinking about things in the correct way, I was wondering if this correct or there is a more "reactive" way of doing it?

What I mean by this is that I have this type that you can register observables with and also this same type will expose the single Observable that I can also subscribe to.

I will try to explain it a little with a code example below.
So, the `SomeTypeWithObservable` just could be one of many types that will expose an `IObservable<SomeEvents>`
The `ReactiveTesting` type is the type that tries to group all the observables together and exposes a single `IObservable<SomEvents>`. There is a `RegisterObservable` method which will send it to the internal `Subject<IObservable<SomeEvents>>`. The constructor sets up the Observable I want to expose as being a `SelectMany` of this subject.

Using the below implementation, in the `ReactiveTesting` constructor I perform a `SelectMany.Publish.RefCount`, following with a dummy subscription to start the observable, I noticed if I didn't use the dummy subscription the registration of observables are not used.

So my **second question** is that code OK to have a dummy subscription to start off the observable, or should I do what I did underneath in the comment where I just had a connectable from Publish and then connected it immediately after, or they are both wrong and in that case, could someone point me in the right direction?

My **third question** Should I be using a subject?

If I call `RegisterObservable` earlier than the subscriptions and if I don't put the dummy `Subscribe` in or the `Connect` then I won't observer any of the events triggered.

My **Fourth question** Could someone explain the latter please? 
I am kind of thinking that because it is `Publish` and `RefCount` then there is nothing to do until there is a subscription which starts off the Observable.

**The code**

**--Edited** - To show there is more than one observable I want to register in `ReactiveTesting`

```
enum SomeEvents
{
    event1,
    event2,
    event3,
    event4
}

interface ISomeTypeWithObservable
{
    IObservable<SomeEvents> SomeObservableEvents { get; }
}

class SomeTypeWithObservable2 : ISomeTypeWithObservable
{
    private event EventHandler SpecialEvent;
    public SomeTypeWithObservable2()
    {
        var observableFromSpecialEvent = Observable.FromEventPattern(h => SpecialEvent += h, h => SpecialEvent -= h).Select(x => SomeEvents.event2);
        SomeObservableEvents = Observable.Create<SomeEvents>(observer =>
            {
                return observableFromSpecialEvent.Subscribe(observer);
            })
            .Publish()
            .RefCount();
    }

    public IObservable<SomeEvents> SomeObservableEvents { get; }
    public void TriggerEvent()
    {
        SpecialEvent.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}

class SomeTypeWithObservable : ISomeTypeWithObservable
{
    private event EventHandler SpecialEvent;
    public SomeTypeWithObservable()
    {
        var observableFromSpecialEvent = Observable.FromEventPattern(h => SpecialEvent += h, h => SpecialEvent -= h).Select(x => SomeEvents.event1);
        SomeObservableEvents = Observable.Create<SomeEvents>(observer =>
            {
                return observableFromSpecialEvent.Subscribe(observer);
            })
        .Publish()
        .RefCount();
    }

    //Some code in here that will produce things to observe, maybe Observable.FromEventPattern...
    public IObservable<SomeEvents> SomeObservableEvents { get; }

    public void TriggerEvent()
    {
        SpecialEvent.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}

class ReactiveTesting
{
    private Subject<IObservable<SomeEvents>> _innerEvents = new Subject<IObservable<SomeEvents>>();

    public IObservable<SomeEvents> AllEvents;
    public ReactiveTesting()
    {
        AllEvents = _innerEvents.SelectMany(x => x).Publish().RefCount();
        AllEvents.Subscribe(next => { }, exception => { }, () => { });

        //This instead of the above??
        //var connectableObservable = _innerEvents.SelectMany(x => x).Publish();
        //AllEvents = connectableObservable;
        //connectableObservable.Connect();
    }

    public void RegisterObservable(ISomeTypeWithObservable someTypeWithObservable)
    {
        _innerEvents.OnNext(someTypeWithObservable.SomeObservableEvents);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var reactiveTesting = new ReactiveTesting();
        var someTypeWithObservable = new SomeTypeWithObservable();
        var someTypeWithObservable2 = new SomeTypeWithObservable2();
        reactiveTesting.AllEvents.Subscribe(next => Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Subscriber 1 - {0}", next.ToString("G"))));
        reactiveTesting.AllEvents.Subscribe(next => Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Subscriber 2 - {0}", next.ToString("G"))));
        reactiveTesting.RegisterObservable(someTypeWithObservable);
        reactiveTesting.RegisterObservable(someTypeWithObservable2);
        someTypeWithObservable.TriggerEvent();
        someTypeWithObservable.TriggerEvent();
        someTypeWithObservable.TriggerEvent();
        someTypeWithObservable2.TriggerEvent();
        someTypeWithObservable2.TriggerEvent();
        someTypeWithObservable2.TriggerEvent();

        Console.WriteLine("Press key...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> So my first question I get a feeling I am not thinking about things in
>   the correct way, I was wondering if this correct or there is a more
>   "reactive" way of doing it?

Using a `Subject` in `ReactiveTesting` is normally a cue that you have some imperative code that could be eliminated, or pushed further out. It may require re-writing some of your surrounding code. In this case, you would end up with something like this:

```
class ReactiveTesting
{
    public IObservable<SomeEvents> AllEvents { get; }
    public ReactiveTesting(IObservable<IObservable<SomeEvents>> eventSource)
    {
        AllEvents = eventSource.Merge().Publish().RefCount();
    }
}
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var someTypeWithObservable = new SomeTypeWithObservable();
        var reactiveTesting = new ReactiveTesting(Observable.Return(someTypeWithObservable.SomeObservableEvents));
        reactiveTesting.AllEvents.Subscribe(next => Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Subscriber 1 - {0}", next.ToString("G"))));
        reactiveTesting.AllEvents.Subscribe(next => Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Subscriber 2 - {0}", next.ToString("G"))));
        someTypeWithObservable.TriggerEvent();
        someTypeWithObservable.TriggerEvent();
        someTypeWithObservable.TriggerEvent();

        Console.WriteLine("Press key...");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

> So my second question is that code OK to have a dummy subscription to
>   start off the observable, or should I do what I did underneath in the
>   comment where I just had a connectable from Publish and then connected
>   it immediately after, or they are both wrong and in that case, could
>   someone point me in the right direction?

It shouldn't be necessary. It works for me the same as removing it. Dummy subscription helps with `.Replay().Refcount()`. I don't see the point with `.Publish()`.

> My third question Should I be using a subject?

They're a code smell basically. If you can eliminate them, or push them away from your business logic, you're better off.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer :-) I think maybe I wasn't clear in what I would like to do. I would like to be able to register many observables with `ReactiveTesting` So `ReactiveTesting` is essentially a singleton and can group all these observables and produce 1. Again maybe I am not thinking about this solution in the correct way, related to Rx. Also the subscriptions could occur before I register/merge a new observable. I thought I would use Publish so I can subscribe later than the registration and still observe the same observable.